# creating mysql tables through python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, conda

I have a problem creating tables. I use the code below and on one machine it works perfectly well. On another machine, it does not give any error but also does not create the tables.  I believe it has something to do with the conda environment but I made a new environment and I still get the same error. There is no difference in library versions between the machine where it works and where it does not work
python=3.7
mysql-connector-python=8.0.18. The funny thing is if I execute a select statement I get valid results.

```
import mysql.connector
import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=config['mysql report server 8']['host'],                           
port= config['mysql report server 8']['port'],
user=config['mysql report server 8']['user'],
password=config['mysql report server 8']['password'],
allow_local_infile=True,
autocommit=1
)
mycursor = conn.cursor()

def create_tables(mycursor,name_of_import:str):
    with open(r"../SupportFiles/Table_Create_Query.sql") as f:
       create_tables_str = f.read()

    create_tables_str =  create_tables_str .replace("xxx_replaceme",name_of_import)
    mycursor.execute(create_tables_str,multi=True)

create_tables(mycursor,"my_test_import")
conn.commit()    
conn.close()
```

the file Table_Create_Query.sql has the following contents

```
use cb_bht3_0_20_048817_raw;
create table xxx_replaceme_categories (
cid  int,
variable varchar(255),
name     varchar(255),
value int,
ordr int,
label varchar(255) 
);
```

Comment: You can't have multiple queries in a single call to `mycursor.execute()`. You need to do a separate call for `use cb_bht3_0_20_048817_raw` and `create table`

Comment: @Barmar I tried leaving one query in the file. i.e. incorporating the schema's name into the create table. It still does not work.

Comment: Either it should execute the query or report an error. I can't think of any way that it would complete without error and not create the table.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. I have been trying to debug this for the last 10 hours. It is driving me crazy.  Now, I  kind-a made it work when I deleted the ,multi=True parameter and made the query one-liner. Still, I do not understand why the initial code it works on one other machine the exact same code with a recent install of conda env while on 3 other machines the same code refuses to work